# Can I use two voltage baluns to make a common mode choke?

Tags: balun, transmission-line

I have two 1:4 voltage baluns. If I connect them together so that I have 1:4-4:1, is that the equivalent of putting a 1:1 common mode choke on my feed line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Say you take just one of the 1:4 baluns, and connect it like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbQGs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the winding ratios are not equal, then equal and opposite currents will not cancel each other's magnetic flux, so there will be a net non-zero flux in the core. Thus, it presents an inductance to common-mode currents.

Now if you add another in series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOTv9p.png)</sup>

there's still non-zero flux in the core. It simply doubles the common-mode impedance.